# how to perform push segue to certain view controller in navigation stack in the different storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboard

I want to perform push segue ( so I can have back button in the top left), from main.storyboard to my another storyboard (second storyboard).

[image]

I want to perform push segue from the red view controller in the main.storyboard to the second (number 2) view controller in the second.storyboard

from here (main.storyboard):
[image]

to here no.2 (second.storyboard) :
[image]

can I do that? what should I do?

Comment: Create a segue from the red scene to scene 2, give it an identifier and then perform it.

Comment: if it enters scene2, it will always be to no.1 not no.2 since the initial view controller in second.storyboard is in the no.1

Comment: No, because you can set a specific scene for the storyboard reference as per the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a reference id for the ViewController you want to push

In the second storyboard

Choose the ViewController on the interface builder

Assign "Storyboard ID" to it (for ex. SecondVC)

Back to the main storyboard

choose the storyboard reference to the "second" storyboard and add the VC id (SecondVC) in the "Referenced ID" field